Can the find command find every new file created during the search process?
Can the find command find every new file created during the search process?
Perhaps can divide it into two types? the directory that has been searched and the directory that is being searched?
For example, I want to list all the files in directory b (including subdirectories), but I have many, many files (tens of thousands). During the listed process, new files will be created in the b directory.
find /a/b -type f -exec ls -l {} \;


I just finished testing and found a strange situation. there are about 20,000 files fitted the condition in directory b, and create 22 new files during the finding. But in the end, 35 files were not moved (meaning not only the 22 new files created, but also 13 additional files). and when i run this command again, these 35 files are all moved to directory c.
find /a/b -maxdepth 1 -mtime -30 -type f -exec mv -iv "{}" /a/c \;


What do you mean by this? What "search process" are you referring to? The find itself, perhaps? Can you provide an example (in your question)?

Are you referring to files that might get created while find is running? Please [edit] your question and explain your use case or what problem you want to solve.

No, of course not. It only walks the tree once, and when it leaves a directory, it doesn't go back.
E.g. this would print all files find encounters, and create a new file world.txt in ./b when visiting ./a, and the other way around. You should only see one world.txt in the resulting output. (Depending on your system, it might be one or the other.)
% mkdir a b
% touch {a,b}/hello.txt
% find . -print \( -path "./a/hello.txt" -exec touch "b/world.txt" \; -o 
                   -path "./b/hello.txt" -exec touch "a/world.txt" \; \)
.
./a
./a/hello.txt
./b
./b/world.txt
./b/hello.txt

But if you look at the tree afterwards, they're both there:
% ls -1 */world.txt
a/world.txt
b/world.txt

If you want to find all newly-created files, you'll need to walk the tree again and again to look for them, or set up something like inotify watches on all directories in the tree (taking care to add new ones when new directories are created). Or perhaps reconsider how the directory structure is used; i.e. create new files in a separate directory.

What happens if it's finding and creating in the same directory instead of different a and b

@hrdom, They will either be seen, or they won't. But does it matter? Are your new files created in sync with find running? If they're created by an unrelated process, then they're likely not synched. And if they're created through something find launches, then you know you're creating them and can take that into account. (Not that you still could force find to see them, but if they need some processing, you can arrange to do that later. The tricky part is avoiding processing them twice, which is why I'd suggest creating new files in a separate directory.)

I just finished testing and found a strange situation. there are about 20,000 files in directory b, and create 22 new files during the finding. But in the end, 35 files were not moved (meaning not only the 22 new files created, but also 13 additional files).

@terdon i have given the command that will move files. and i'm not sure what the command is for the action that created files, it's a little complex.

You have indeed, @hrdom, sorry. I posted that comment before noticing your edit.
